# How to pass extra fields for post with file upload in ajax codeiginter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am upload a file in php codeigniter project using a ajax. The file is uploading succesfully. But I also want to post some extra values to database with this. I am not sure how to do it. Can anybody please tell me how to pass another data fields while saving a file in php

Here is my js code

```
$("#btnupdatecover").click(function(event){

    alert(coverPostion);

     if($("#fileuploadcover").val() != ''){
        if (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') {

      var form = $('#formname').get(0); 
    var formData = new FormData(form);  

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Userpage/updatedp",
      data: formData,
      mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
      dataType: 'json',
      xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
      },
      cache:false,                    
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(result){


       toastr8.info({
      message:'Profile Picture Updated', 
        title:"New Image Uploaded",
        iconClass: "fa fa-info",
           // imgURI: ["https://unsplash.it/120/120?image=20"]
    });
       clearAll();
      }                       
    });
    // 
     event.preventDefault();

        }  

}
else
{
     toastr8.info({
      message:'Error Occured', 
        title:"Please try again",
        iconClass: "fa fa-info",
   // imgURI: ["https://unsplash.it/120/120?image=20"]
    });
}

});
```

My PHP Code

```
public function updatedp()
    {
    $var = $_FILES ['fileUp'];
    $img=$_FILES ['fileUp'];
    $config['upload_path'] = 'webim/dp_images'; 
    $config['overwrite'] = 'TRUE';
    $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config["max_size"] = '1400';
    $config["max_width"] = '1400';
    $config["max_height"] = '1400';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('fileUp')) 
    {               
        $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors(); 
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$this->data['error']));
        exit;
    } 
    else 
    { 

            $data=array('active'=>0);
            $this->db->where('userid','1');
            $this->db->update('music_user_dp',$data);

            $uname['uname'] =$this->session->all_userdata('uname');
            $uname['id'] =$this->session->all_userdata('id');
            $post_data = array(
            'id' => '',
            'userid' => $uname['id']['id'], 
            'profilepic'=>$var['name'], 
            'updatedate' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'active' => '1'
           );
          $this->Userpage_model->insert_dp_to_db($post_data);
          echo json_encode(array("result"=>"Success"));
          exit;
    }
    }
```

I just pass extra fields with this to post in database.

Thanks

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload The poster asked how to send files using Ajax but their example shows how to pass additional data.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this:

**Approach 1**

Use hidden fields into the form.

**Approach 2**

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Userpage/updatedp",
      data: {formData: formData, var1: 'value', var2: 'value'},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){


       toastr8.info({
      message:'Profile Picture Updated', 
        title:"New Image Uploaded",
        iconClass: "fa fa-info",
           // imgURI: ["https://unsplash.it/120/120?image=20"]
    });
       clearAll();
      }                       
    });
```

Now these value you will get your controller.

Comment: if you still need any help let me know.

Comment: I am not able to fetch the values in controller. its give me null

Comment: public function updateCover()
    {
  var_dump($this->input->post('var1'));
 exit;
}

Its give me null

Comment: Make sure there is no jquery error while sending the ajax request.

Comment: Are you sure the url (Userpage/updatedp) passed into ajax request is sending request to updateCover() method.

Comment: Yes because the image is saving in database succesfully.. I have checked it

Comment: after this I got error TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: there was a spelling mistake again copy the code and use it